# Mapping 2 tables to single entity in Entity Framework Fluent API with different primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I have a class:

```
public class FormTemplate
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual string Shifr { get; set; }

    public virtual FormType FormType { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }
}
```

and i need to split it into to tables in db. I have a fluent mapping wich do this for me:

```
en.Map(m =>
{
    m.Properties(_ => new {_.Code, _.Name, _.Shifr});
    m.ToTable("Table1");
})
.Map(m =>
{
    m.Properties(_ => new {_.ActivationDate});
    m.ToTable("Table2");
}).HasRequired(t => t.FormType).WithMany().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapKey("FormType");
    m.ToTable("Table2");
});
```

It works fine, but creates two tables with same primary key column "Id". Is it possible to map first table PK to column "Id" and second table PK to column "Form" ?

Comment: How would you know which Table1 row goes with which Table2 row, then?

Comment: I only need to change column names, it steel has to store same values for row.